# Preservation of a scalar product under the action of an isomorphism

Tags: linear-transformations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

Introduce the following assumptions and definitions,

- $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a bounded Lipshitz domain,
- $(L^2(\Omega))^3$ the space of vector square integrable functions,
- $M$ a $3\times 3$ real symmetric positive definite matrix (so $M$ is invertible),
- $A: (L^2(\Omega))^3\to (L^2(\Omega))^3$ a bounded self adjoint operator which satisfies:
  $$
  AM\neq MA
  $$
  and
  $$
   0\leq (u,Au)\leq \| u\|^2 ,\;\forall u\in (L^2(\Omega))^3,
  $$
  where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the $L^2$ scalar product and $\|\cdot\|$ is the associated norm.
  Then, I want to check if we have or not the following property:
  $$
   0\leq (u,(M^{-1}AM)u)\leq \| u\|^2 ,\;\forall u\in (L^2(\Omega))^3.
  $$
  I know that the operator $M^{-1}AM$ defined on $(L^2(\Omega))^3$ is spectrally equivalent to $A$ but I don't know how to use it to check the above inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already fails in the scalar case. Consider
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad M=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Both are selfadjoint and invertible, and $\|A\|=1$, so $(u,Au)\leq \|u\|^2$. We have
$$
M^{-1}AM=\begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} -1&-2\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\bigg(\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix} ,M^{-1}AM\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix} \bigg)=\bigg(\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -2\\2\end{bmatrix}\bigg)=2>1=\bigg\|\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix}\bigg\|^2.
$$

---

**Edit: controlling $M$ is not enough.**

Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad M=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2&1/4\\1/4&1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\|M\|=3/4$ and
$$
M^{-1}AM=\frac13\begin{bmatrix} -1&-2\\ 2&4\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
\bigg(\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix} ,M^{-1}AM\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix} \bigg)=\bigg(\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -2/3\\4/3\end{bmatrix}\bigg)=\frac43>1=\bigg\|\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix}\bigg\|^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can we find additive assumptions on the matrix $M$ for which the inequality becomes true? For example if we add $\|M\|<1$?

Comment: Controlling the norm of $M$ or $M^{-1}$ alone is not enough (see the example). If you require both $\|M\|\leq1$ and $\|M^{-1}\|\leq1$ then $M$ is a unitary and of course the inequality holds.